# Keep EXACT words from R corpus

Tags: r, regex, text-mining, corpus

From answer posted on: Keep document ID with R corpus by @MrFlick

I am trying to slightly modify what is a great example.

**Question:** How do I modify the *`content_transformer` function* to keep only **exact** words? You can see in the inspect output that wonderful is counted as wonder and ratio is counted as rationale. I do not have a strong understanding of `gregexpr` and `regmatches`.

Create data frame:

```
dd <- data.frame(
  id = 10:13,
  text = c("No wonderful, then, that ever",
           "So that in many cases such a ",
           "But there were still other and",
           "Not even at the rationale")
  , stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

Now, in order to read special attributes from a data.frame, we will use the `readTabular` function to make our own custom data.frame reader

```
library(tm)
myReader <- readTabular(mapping = list(content = "text", id = "id"))
```

specify the column to use for the contents and the id in the data.frame. Now we read it in with `DataframeSource` but use our custom reader.

```
tm <- VCorpus(DataframeSource(dd), readerControl = list(reader = myReader))
```

Now if we want to only keep a certain set of words, we can create our own content_transformer function. One way to do this is

```
  keepOnlyWords <- content_transformer(function(x, words) {
        regmatches(x, 
            gregexpr(paste0("\\b(",  paste(words, collapse = "|"), "\\b)"), x)
        , invert = T) <- " "
        x
    })
```

This will replace everything that's not in the word list with a space. Note that you probably want to run `stripWhitespace` after this. Thus our transformations would look like

```
keep <- c("wonder", "then", "that", "the")

tm <- tm_map(tm, content_transformer(tolower))
tm <- tm_map(tm, keepOnlyWords, keep)
tm <- tm_map(tm, stripWhitespace)
```

Inspect dtm matrix:

```
> inspect(dtm)
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 4, terms: 4)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 7/9
Sparsity           : 56%
Maximal term length: 6
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

    Terms
Docs ratio that the wonder
  10     0    1   1      1
  11     0    1   0      0
  12     0    0   1      0
  13     1    0   1      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching grammars to `tidytext`, your current transformation would be

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)

dd %>% unnest_tokens(word, text) %>% 
    mutate(word = str_replace_all(word, setNames(keep, paste0('.*', keep, '.*')))) %>% 
    inner_join(data_frame(word = keep))

##   id   word
## 1 10 wonder
## 2 10    the
## 3 10   that
## 4 11   that
## 5 12    the
## 6 12    the
## 7 13    the
```

Keeping exact matches is easier, as you can use joins (which use `==`) instead of regex:

```
dd %>% unnest_tokens(word, text) %>% 
    inner_join(data_frame(word = keep))

##   id word
## 1 10 then
## 2 10 that
## 3 11 that
## 4 13  the
```

To take it back to a document-term matrix,

```
library(tm)

dd %>% mutate(id = factor(id)) %>%    # to keep empty rows of DTM
    unnest_tokens(word, text) %>% 
    inner_join(data_frame(word = keep)) %>% 
    mutate(i = 1) %>% 
    cast_dtm(id, word, i) %>% 
    inspect()

## <<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 4, terms: 3)>>
## Non-/sparse entries: 4/8
## Sparsity           : 67%
## Maximal term length: 4
## Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
## 
##     Terms
## Docs then that the
##   10    1    1   0
##   11    0    1   0
##   12    0    0   0
##   13    0    0   1
```

---

Currently, your function is matching `words` with a boundary before *or* after. To change it to before *and* after, change the `collapse` parameter to include boundaries:

```
tm <- VCorpus(DataframeSource(dd), readerControl = list(reader = myReader))

keepOnlyWords<-content_transformer(function(x,words) {
        regmatches(x, 
            gregexpr(paste0("(\\b",  paste(words, collapse = "\\b|\\b"), "\\b)"), x)
        , invert = T) <- " "
        x
    })

tm <- tm_map(tm, content_transformer(tolower))
tm <- tm_map(tm, keepOnlyWords, keep)
tm <- tm_map(tm, stripWhitespace)

inspect(DocumentTermMatrix(tm))

## <<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 4, terms: 3)>>
## Non-/sparse entries: 4/8
## Sparsity           : 67%
## Maximal term length: 4
## Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
## 
##     Terms
## Docs that the then
##   10    1   0    1
##   11    1   0    0
##   12    0   0    0
##   13    0   1    0
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. works great! @alistaire

Answer (score 1):

I got same result as @alistaire with tm, with the following modified line in keepOnlyWords content transformer first defined by @BEMR:

```
gregexpr(paste0("\\b(",  paste(words, collapse = "|"), ")\\b"), x)
```

There was a misplaced ")" in gregexpr first specified by @BEMR i.e. should be ")\\b" not "\\b)"

I think the above gregexpr is equivalent to that specified by @alistaire:

```
gregexpr(paste0("(\\b",  paste(words, collapse = "\\b|\\b"), "\\b)"), x)
```